# Unable to use QTP's free license

Tags: qtp

I have a problem with QTP (Quick Test Professional). While trying to install the QTP free license, by mistake I clicked on "Seat License", then I clicked Cancel. Now I'm unable to use the free license because it asks for key for a seat license or concurrent license.

I have tried to reinstall QTP, but nothing changed - I'm still unable to use the free license.

Is there any workaround for this problem instead of formatting and reinstalling Windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you have selected seat license and then cancel the demo license should not be affected.
Make sure you are still in seat license mode.

If you can upload image of the error message maybe I can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

1 - (win + R / appwiz.cpl / enter )  
uninstall QTP \ hp update \ hp result viewer

2 - remove (Mercury Interactive) from registry HKCU\software\ and HKLM\software

3 - re-install QTP